# Arrangement properties in WPF styles

Tags: wpf, styles, skinning

Is it normal to store Alignments, Margins, Paddings and other arrangement properties in styles?

Comment: Depends on your needs. If e.g. all expanders should have equal distance from there neighbor controls. Then why not?

Comment: As opposed to within the element? It is your choice, styles help in separating the styles out from the element markup and therefore apply to multiple elements as well.